# Blender texturebaking not working (combing all textures into one)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I created a 3d model with a 3d scanning software called meshroom
. When I import the model into blender, the material of the object is divided into many textures (Pic.2). Now I try to combine them all into one. I have to say I never did this before, and so I watched two videos on YouTube.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4)

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw)

I created a second UV map called UV2 and created a node group in all textures with the image texture (called horse_color_bake) I want to bake it on (just a black 1024x1024
image). Then I just clicked on bake after changing the values on diffuse and Color (Pic.3). After I waited for some time, blender just crashes. Before that I get a note which says: "
Circular dependency for Image "
texture_1017.png"
from object "
horse 1"
. In another file I added the same textures on two cubes and tried it as well. It worked there perfectly fine. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Pic.1:[image]

Pic.2:[image]

Pic.3:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help to solve your problem (Without having the scene here):

[image: Baking problem. Possible answer.]

Comment: Additional info: This works only, if you have unwrapped your model in "UV2". If there are no uv islands in "UV2", then Blender may crash in your situation.

Comment: This helped! Thank you very much for the fast and well made answer!